# ComponentNotFound exception Castle.Windsor

Tags: exception, castle-windsor

I am trying to get started with Castle.Windsor and following a comment I made on the samples currently available for newbies (http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Silvertlight_Sample_App_Customer_contact_manager.ashx?Discuss=1), I thought I'd take the bull by the horns and update the example provided here http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/InversionOfControlAndDependencyInjectionWithCastleWindsorContainerPart1.aspx.

This is a simple and fairly straightforward console application making use of Castle Windsor, albeit an outdated version. My Main method in Program.cs is as follows:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
        var retriever = container.Resolve<IHtmlTitleRetriever>();

        Console.WriteLine(retriever.GetTitle(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileUri"])));

        Console.Read();

        container.Dispose();
    }
```

and the Service and Components, which are all in the same file i.e. Program.cs are thus:

```
public interface IHtmlTitleRetriever
{
    string GetTitle(Uri file);

}

public interface IFileDownloader
{
    string Download(Uri file);
}

public interface ITitleScraper
{
    string Scrape(string fileContents);
}

public class HtmlTitleRetriever: IHtmlTitleRetriever
{
    private readonly IFileDownloader _downloader;
    private readonly ITitleScraper _scraper;

    public HtmlTitleRetriever(IFileDownloader dowloader, ITitleScraper scraper)
    {
        _downloader = dowloader;
        _scraper = scraper;
    }

    public string GetTitle(Uri file)
    {
        string fileContents = _downloader.Download(file);
        return _scraper.Scrape(fileContents);
    }
}



public class HttpFileDownloader : IFileDownloader
{
    public string Download(Uri file)
    {
        return new WebClient().DownloadString(file);
    }
}

public class StringParsingTitleScraper : ITitleScraper
{
    public string Scrape(string fileContents)
    {
        string title = string.Empty;
        int openingTagIndex = fileContents.IndexOf("<title>");
        int closingTagIndex = fileContents.IndexOf("</title>");

        if(openingTagIndex != -1 && closingTagIndex != -1)
            title = fileContents.Substring(openingTagIndex, closingTagIndex - openingTagIndex).Substring(7);

        return title;
    }
}
```

It is pretty much a straight copy of what Simone Busoli has from his example. The code compiles fine but I get the following error when I run the application:

> No component for supporting the service WindsorSample.IHtmlTitleRetriever was found

I understand what that means but I don't know what I'm doing wrong that the components are not getting loaded into the container. I'm using Castle.Windsor 2.5.2 and .NET 4.0.

Looking forward to the answers,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Krzysztof's advice, here is how to get my simple example going:

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

       // container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
        container.Register(
            Component.For( typeof( IHtmlTitleRetriever ) ).ImplementedBy( typeof(HtmlTitleRetriever) ) ,
            Component.For( typeof( IFileDownloader ) ).ImplementedBy( typeof( HttpFileDownloader ) ),
            Component.For( typeof( ITitleScraper ) ).ImplementedBy( typeof( StringParsingTitleScraper ) )
         );
        var retriever = container.Resolve<IHtmlTitleRetriever>();

        Console.WriteLine(retriever.GetTitle(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileUri"])));

        Console.Read();

        container.Dispose();
    }
```

That will work.

---

Krzysztof, we also tried this

```
 container.Register(
            AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().Pick().If(Component.IsCastleComponent)
        );
```

and adorned all the classes appropriately but I still got the same error as before. Can you shed some light on this please?

Comment: Did you mark the `HtmlTitleRetriever` with `[CastleComponent(typeof(IHtmlTitleRetriever ), Lifestyle = LifestyleType.Transient)]`? `IsCastleComponent` picks up classes with this attribute only. If you want to register components without them being decorated with any attribute you can do it, using fluent API as described in the documentation. Use Debugger view of the container to gain visibility into what gets registered and how.

Comment: Ah I see where I was going wrong :). I had typeof(HtmlTitleRetriever). Thank you for your time and patience. I am planning on writing a tutorial on this so that others can set up Windsor much quicker. If you're interested I could let you know when that is done so that others can benefit and I can also have some editorial control. :)

Comment: sure. You can also contribute that to Windsor's documentation wiki if you want.

Comment: Hey Krzysztof, as promised, here's my blog entry. http://davidsiew.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/getting-started-with-castle-windsor-tutorial-part-1/. Let me know how I can improve on it. Then when it's better, I'll put it on Windsor's documentation wiki.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - awesome you're updating the sample. As you mentioned, an even smaller sample, without Silverlight overhead will certainly be useful.

As for your question - the exception means that the service you requested, `IHtmlTitleRetriever` is not supported by any component you registered, in other words - you didn't seem to have registered `IHtmlTitleRetriever` in the container at all. How does your installer look like? To check if components get registered properly you can put a breakpoint in the line after you call `Install` and see what components were registered, and if that's what you were expecting. It's quite useful for quickly diagnosing issues like the one you're having. ([see the documentation here](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Debugger-views.ashx)).

If you're still not sure what the reason is, make sure your installer classes are all public, and post their code here so that we can try to figure out what's the reason.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof, I must admit that I'm confused here. I don't understand what you mean by "you didn't seem to have registered IHtmlTitleRetriever in the container at all". My understanding was that by using "container.Install(FromAssembly.This());", the IHtmlTitleRetriever would be registered in the container as per http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx. Can you please clarify?

Comment: yes, provided you have some `IWindsorInstaller`s in that assembly and one of them is registering the component for `IHtmlTitleRetriever`

Comment: to quote the documentation: ''Installers are simply types that implement the IWindsorInstaller interface. The interface has a single method called Install. The method gets an instance of the container, which it can then register components with using fluent registration API''

Comment: Hi Krzysztof, the senior dev who introduced me to Castle Windsor found out what the problem was. Yes you are right, I wasn't registering the component as you rightly pointed out.